# Adding indexes to existing database

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have database with tables full of data. I would like to add indexes ( both clustered and non-clustered). Is it possible to add indexes without having to insert this data again ( I mean create new DB with indexes and export data from the old one to new one)? As I know clustered indexes are saved physically which means I won't be able to do that without recreating DB. But still, is it possible to add indexes to existing database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to add indexes without having to insert this data again?

Yes. Not only is it possible, it makes little sense to remove the data before adding the indexes.

Adding an index to a large table may take a long time though.

Comment: So what would be better approach? Delete data, add indexes and insert data or simply add indexes. I have approx 40 tables with 1M records each.

Comment: Especially if you go from having no clustered index and then you add a clustered index -> the whole table will be shuffled around, physically, on disk -> takes a long time, but well worth the effort!

Comment: @seeker - 1M records is not that much. The normal approach is to simply add the indexes. However, this can be CPU and IO intensive and as such you need to consider the impact on your users. Schedule this so minimize disruptions. If you have a good backup of the DB, try it on a test machine to see how long it would take.